# Strange "undefined method `absolute_path'" error

Tags: ruby

When I try to do this ([real code](http://snipt.org/smlpk2)):

```
fh = File.new("a file name",  "w")
fh_path = File.absolute_path(fh)
```

I get an `` undefined method `absolute_path' for File:Class (NoMethodError) ``

In the Ruby documentation is says: absolute_path is a method of File so I don't understand this `NoMethodError`.  Am I using the method wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check your Ruby version. The method `absolute_path` was [added in 1.9.1](http://apidock.com/ruby/File/absolute_path/class), it seems.

Comment: Thanks, that was it.  I think I accidentally downgraded when trying to install RVM